# Lifetime of lightbulbs and almost-sure convergence

Tags: probability

[image]

Let $(L_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be a sequence of iid lifetimes of bulbs. For the trivial case we can say $1/E(L_1) = \infty$.

Let $T_k$ be the sum of Li's up to the $k$th bulb. By the strong law of large numbers $T_k/k\rightarrow E(L_1)=0$ almost surely. Then $T_k = 0$ almost surely.

I know $P(T_k >t) = P(N_t<k)$. How could I conclude that $N_t = \infty$ almost surely such that the equality is established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E(L)=0$, then we could possibly have $\sum_{i=1}^k L_i < \infty$, in which case $N_t$ becomes infinite for some finite $t$, and the proof is trivial.  If on the other hand $0 < E(L) \leqslant \infty$, then the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k L_i$ is unbounded with $k$.  So consider $\sum_{i=1}^k L_i \leqslant t < \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} L_i$.  We can always find such $k$ for all $t$.  This gives us
$$
\frac{1}{N_t}\sum_{i=1}^k L_i \leqslant \frac{t}{N_t} < \frac{1}{N_t}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} L_i ~.
\tag{Eq.1}
$$
Now $N_t = k$, but regardless,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} L_i }{ \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} L_i } = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{k+1}{k} = 1 ~.
$$
So we can take a limit on (Eq.1) to see that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{N_t}{t} = \frac{1}{E(L)}. ~ \blacksquare$

Comment: Ah I missed the link between t and k. Thanks for the help.